# face Removal using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

hi I want to detect and tracking the hand using skin color based but I don't need to see face or any skin color ( I mean i need just left hand to tracking) in output video.
thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Range for finding skin color in YCrCb
Low_YCrCb = np.array([0,125,80],np.uint8)
High_YCrCb = np.array([255,169,133],np.uint8)


while True 

    # grab frames from Video
    _, img = videoFrame.read()

    # Convert to YCrCb --
    img_YCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

    # Find ROI in YCrCb 
    skin_ROI = cv2.inRange(img_YCrCb, Low_YCrCb, High_YCrCb)

    # Find contour in skin region
    _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skinROI, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Draw the contour --
    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 500:
            cv2.drawContours(img, contours, i, (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # Results
    cv2.imshow('Result',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('Result')
videoFrame.release()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can train [OpenCV haar cascades](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0). It works well for face detection and should also work for hand detection

Comment: Thanks vitalii  I train OpenCV haar cascades but it doesn't work well, So I want to using skin color and I want just hand

Comment: @AmoorEng maybe your train/validation set was not very good? Anyway skin color based algorithm will have many heuristics and it's not universal solution. Maybe you'd try deep learning frameworks such as **Theano** or **Caffe**

Comment: Thanks I will See Theano or Caffe